# Need to cap voltage at 12V, and need to vary voltage down

Tags: 12v

I tried to find something like this in the knowledge base, but didn't see a perfect match.

I have a small submersible pump. 12VDC, 4.8W. Model DC30a-1230.

I assume that is 0.4amps.

There seem to be a few pumps out there with this model designation, but the amps vary slightly.

Here's some detail for a similar pump:

- Power consumption 0.55W~4.2W (can be customized within this range)
- Rated voltage 12VDC
- Working voltage range 5VCD ~ 12VDC
- Max load current  0.35A @12VDC

I'm willing to accept that lower amperage value for my needs.

I will be powering this off of a 12V car battery.  The battery, at full charge, can approach 13V, and maybe a little over.  So, I want to cap that (unless these devices can handle a little extra).

I want to be able to vary the pump speed.  What circuit do I need?  I'll be plugging this into a 12V cigarette lighter receptacle hooked to the battery.

So, what circuit do I need, and do I need to regulate the max voltage?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if that pump can't work fine on 13V. [The manufacturer](http://www.dcbrushlesspump.com/Mini-Dc-Pump(DC30A)-p66.html) explicitly states: `Power supply Solar panel; DC electric source; battery`

Comment: Don't assume: `4.8W/12V = 400mA`. You're right.

Comment: Try to search for "computer fan speed regulator circuit"

Answer (score 2):

I'd also say it'll be fine on 13v.

For that low power draw a quick & dirty answer would be to put a couple of diodes in series with it to give about a volt drop, or use an LM7812.

These days, you can get complete LM317 adjustable regulators with heatsinks on a PCB from eBay china for like $2 so that's another option.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 555 to PWM the motor's supply, as shown below.

It runs at about 10Hz with the component values shown, and the duty cycle can be adjusted with R2 - to control the motor's speed without loss of torque - from about 1% to about 99% of full speed.

The frequency can be increased or decreased by decreasing or increasing, respectively, the value of C1.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you could use a [programmable power supply](http://www.linear.com/parametric/Digitally_Programmable_Regulators) chip.  Linear has a good selection as well as TI and other semiconductor companies.  A chip with VID (voltage id) lines would probably be best for you since the values are hard-coded and described in the datasheet and makes it very easy to control from a simple microcontroller.

While these are pretty awesome, they can be difficult to deisgn around.  The concept of your application would be you just regulate at 12v and the slowly bring it down with the VID lines if you need to.

This'll probably get downvoted into oblivion since it isn't exactly hobbyist level.  There may be other solutions but this is the first one that comes to my late-night mind.

Comment: This won't get downvoted into oblivion but come on, OP just need a transistor and a potentiometer.

Comment: You should put that into an answer.  I just don't know about simple circuits like this.
I'm not sure how far that will work though if OP wants to take a more wireless advanced path.

Comment: Well, to be fair, since he's running off a battery, switching is probably a better idea than regulating linearly (assuming he wants to be able to vary the power down significantly). He can probably save a Watt or so if he's going to normally operate at ~3.5W, say.